# Unable to set enviroment variables from parameters in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have a simple Jenkins job,

That's trying to execute this script under (Execute shell script on a remote host using ssh
)

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/regression_auto_run.sh $CATEGORY $BRANCH
```

$CATEGORY and $BRANCH are set as parameters.

But while running the job using parameters, I always get this error in the console.

```
[SSH] executing pre build script:
CATEGORY="remap"
BRANCH="phase5.3"

#!/bin/sh
/path/to/regression_auto_run.sh $CATEGORY $BRANCH
CATEGORY=remap: Command not found.
BRANCH=phase5.3: Command not found.
/bin/sh: Event not found.
CATEGORY: Undefined variable.
```

When I executed the `BRANCH="phase5.3"`  manually in my remote host, i found that it is also throwing `Command not found.` error

To set the environment variable, I need to use `set BRANCH="phase5.3"` in my host but I see that Jenkins is trying to execute `BRANCH="phase5.3"` this command.

When I go  `/bin/sh` and then try `BRANCH="phase5.3"` in the host machine, it is working. But from Jenkins, although I have specified this before the script, Jenkins is trying to set the variables before that.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to use `export CATEGORY="remap"`

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko export also works. But Jenkins sets env variable by simply assigning.

Comment: Is `/regression_auto_run.sh` really at the root level ? Did you mean `./regression_auto_run.sh` ?

Comment: It's not at the root level.  I just removed the whole path while posting this question.

Comment: Updated path in the question to avoid confusion.